# How to add class to outer div which contains a particular inner class with jquery?

Tags: jquery

How to add class to "outer" if there is a div with class "inner"?

From

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner>
   blah blah
  </div>
</div>
```

to

```
<div class="outer newclass">
  <div class="inner>
   blah blah
  </div>
</div>
```

Please help. thanks guys.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/addclass/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Solution 1:** You need to use `:has` selector:

```
$('.outer:has(.inner)').addClass('newclass');
```

**Solution 2:** Or, find the inner element and add class to its parent element with class `.outer`:

```
$('.inner').closest('.outer').addClass('newclass');
```

Comment: Solution 1 did it, but the 2nd solution doesn't seem to work.  :)

Comment: @wjR.: is outer div immediate parent of inner div. if not then you will have to use `.closest()` instead of `.parent()`

Comment: Not immediate. Yup .closest maybe the solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
if($('.outer div').hasClass('inner')) {
  $('.outer').addClass('new_class');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.inner').closest('.outer').addClass('newclass');
```

Comment: It is good practice to write some notes as to why would this resolve the OP's issue. Even tough this might be the correct answer higher value is usually given to answers with some written explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) function. See below example :

```
$('.inner').closest('.outer').addClass('newclass');
```

Wherever you want to display output, its depend on your html structure and css definition. Then, the jquery selector will depend on that.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the parent function of jquery

https://jsfiddle.net/bj7k3j0q/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.inner').parent(".outer").addClass("newClass");
});
```